# Python list of list initialize

Tags: python, list

I know that

```
[[]] * 10
```

will give 10 references of the same empty, And

```
[[] for i in range(10)]
```

will give 10 empty lists. But in this example:

```
def get_list(thing):
  return [thing for i in range(10)]
a = get_list([])
a[0].append(1)
print(a)
```

Why the result is again

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Unlike question [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) , I understand that Python doesn't do copy in `[x]*10`.

But why `[]` is special in `[[] for i in range(10)]` ? I think this is inconsistent. Instead of creating a empty list `[]` then pass to `[ ___ for i in range(10)]`, Python take "[]" literally and execute "[]" for every `i`.

Comment: then what are you expect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Because in this case your list consists of 10 references to the list referenced by `thing` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

That is because `thing` is the same list.

In `[[] for i in range(10)]` a new list is generated every time.

In `[thing for i in range(10)]` it's always the list named `thing`.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand why I'm wrong. I answer my question:

I misunderstood the list comprehension in python

```
[ ___ for i in range(10)]
```

It's not like passing a augment to a function. List comprehension execute your expression literally each time in its loop.

The expression `[]` in `[ [] for i in range(10)]` is executed each time so you get a new empty list for each entry.

Same for `[thing for i in range(10)]`. expression `thing` is executed, and the result is alway the same: a reference to one empty list.